# How to mount NAS folders via direct wired connection?

Tags: mount, samba, nas

There are two machines connected to each other via network cable. One is notebook Ubuntu 12.04. Another is NAS Western Digital with a Debian.

The NAS has some files shared via samba. I am not sure how it is called but under Windows these files are accessible via path \mybooklive\public. I know there is NFS - probably it is preferable over samba...

So, how to get my files accessible from Ubuntu when a cable is plugged?

Answer (score 1):

In nautilus menu Go/Network, you should see your NAS. Click on the right icon and it will be mounted.

You can access to it in a terminal here : $HOME/.gvfs/...

Comment: I see another PC, but not the NAS there.

Answer (score 1):

For using from local LAN:

If you are unable to mount the WDmycloud on file, you need to just go to the network connections -> ethernet (only if you are directly connecting NAS drive to PC) -> edit any available connection -> In IPv4 settings -> Make Method = 'link local'.

Done!

You will be able to find the Wdmycloud in browse network option!